# cloud file storage (SSHFS usable?)

Tags: centos, cloud, sshfs, cloud-storage

I am using Linode and plan on having multiple VPS behind a Load Balancer to run my application.

The problem i have is with storage, in the next year i see at least 2TB of storage required.

I have been researching and found that i need Network File Storage or SSH File Storage, as Linode dont have storage space i think i need to use SSH File Storage.

My Questions are :

Is SSH File Storage a viable option in terms of speed and reliability/connectivity?

Is SSH File Storage what i am looking for or is there a better alternative?

I am using Centos if that makes a difference (I can change distro if needed)

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for 'how to host a large storage system in a VPS environment without native support for it'.

Comment: You really haven't provided anywhere near enough information for us to be able to answer your first or second questions - we don't know what your project is or what it's doing so all we could really say is `maybe`. Your last question is a shopping question which generally don't do well here.

Answer (score 0):

sshfs has a lot of overhead, and has been quite slow in my experience, compared with other transports like NFS or iSCSI.

For this application, where you have several app servers reading and serving the same data from a central file share, NFS really is your best bet.

If you're on Linode, you can always run your own NFS server on one of your VPSes, or go shopping for a completely different provider. Some *do* offer straight-up NFS file storage. (Though, note that we don't do product/service recommendations here, so don't ask here.)